# Как разделить прелоадер от сайта?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть сайт, который состоит из:

1) прелоадера, который отсчитывает прогресс загрузки видео из пункта №2
2) видео, которое запускается после прелоадера
3) страница роутера

Прелоадер сейчас реализован, как компонент всего SPA на Vue.js.

У прелоадера более 400 строк кода HTML, JS, CSS так как присутствует сложная анимация.

js Бандл проекта весит 1.5 мб и на плохом интернете прелоадер появляется только после загрузки app.js, то есть может пройти 40 секунд до появляения прелоадера.

Вопрос: как разделить бандл на 2 части, чтобы грузился сначала preloader.js, а потом app.js и при этом я мог из этих двух банлов в друг друга передавать переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что дело в том, что пока не загрузиться код js, ничего не отображается, а это может занять и продолжительное время. Это проблема довольно таки известная и имеет уже готовое решение - директива [`v-cloak`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak). Эта директива используется для оторажения html, который показывает до того, как начнется выполнение кода js, и скрывается перед началом его выполнения.

Если же Вам нужно именно разделить код на несколько частей, то есть вариант с [`динамическим компонентом`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B). Т.е. возможно выделить компонент как отдельно подгружаемый, и до его полной загрузки выполнять основной код независимо от этого компонента. Понятно, что код без этого компонента будет меньше по объему и загрузиться быстрее. Данные же возможно передавать стандатно через свойства. Так же в таком случае в Ваших руках будет полностью весь процесс загрузки компонента, Вы сможете загружать его там и тогда, где он на самом деле необходим.

Еще есть вариант с [`ленивой загрузки путей`](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/advanced/lazy-loading.html), но, возможно, он Вам не подойдет: тут получается так, что отдельная страница подгружается перед переходом на нее, т.е. есть несколько bandl`ов, которые подгружются динамически при измении пути в компоненте vue-router. Из плюсов то, что этот метод уже заранее подготовлен и количество изменений, которые необходимо внести в проект минимальны.